# Reinstall/Recover a single program

Tags: restore, reinstall

In the case I can't find any installer, portable version or source code of a software I want to reinstall (or looking for one of those would require too long), there is any utility for Windows or Linux systems which allows to reinstall/recover a single program which has been previously uninstalled?

As far as I know System Restore would recover any uninstalled software, but it would also remove any software installation, change or operation happend in the meanwhile.

I guess I'm looking for something that can create an archive or installer of all the program files, configuration files, registry entries, etc. affected by the uninstallation of a single program.

Comment: I would try to help, but I can't get my head around how Google works either...

Comment: No, unless the install was performed through another application, which logged the diff. Even that may not be sufficient, as windows may have updated shared dlls that the prior install needed to know about, or changes in the environment may leave configuration and registry data from the prior install in an invalid state now.

Comment: @FrankThomas that's what my question was meant to ask. does a log of the required information exist, either through Windows or a third-party software? Is the information involved all stored in registry entries, dll's and .ini files?

Comment: only if it is created by a third party software. otherwise, no.

Comment: ...all I can think of are uninstallers like Revo or automatic updaters like Chocolatey.

uninistallers should be able to track the changes made by any single program (or claim to do so.. ), but I don't know if any of them keeps any useful backup information to reinstall the program.

Comment: i don't know why pple mark down your question,cause it is good question! :)
i marked it 1 up! :)

Comment: you forgot to one up my answer ;-)

Comment: I would, but I still lack 2 reps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use system restore,then use [System Restore Explorer](http://nicbedford.co.uk/software/systemrestoreexplorer/) (download link - [InstallSystemRestoreExplorer.msi](http://nicbedford.co.uk/files/InstallSystemRestoreExplorer.msi)
it simply mount your system restore point and you can search for what you want!
Visit site for more information! :)
[image]
[image]